# Minimum no of operations required to create String A By appending subsequence of String B to a empty string C

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

You have given two strings A and B. You have some empty string C. In one operation You can remove any no of characters (from anywhere) from String B and append it to string C. Minimum no of operations required to convert String C to String A.

e.g if
**A is "ABCDE" and 
B is "ABDEC"** then 
In 1st operation you will choose subsequence ABC from B and in 2nd operation DE.

So two operations are required.

if 
**A is "ABCDE"
B is "EDCBA" then 
 operations required  5**.

**Linear complexity expected O(n)**

Comment: @SomeDude LCS will not give the right answer. For example, LCS between `ABCDE` and `ABDEC` is `ABDE`, but we need `ABC`. This issue arises since we can only `append` to `C`.

Comment: @vivek_23 I see I missed the append, thinking of "insert". deleted my comment.

Comment: @trincot I have done this problem with NLogN complexity. Just want to know if it can be done in linear complexity

Comment: @user3902462 just for curiosity, can you share the O(N log N) approach?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a greedy algorithm.

1 - Let `i = 0`
2 - Let `j = 0`
3 - Search for the first `A[i]` in `B` after `j`
4 - If it exists, let `j` be its index in `B`, remove it from `B`, append it to `C`, increment `i`, and repeat from 3
5 - If it doesn't exist, repeat from 2

Each time you get to 5 corresponds to one operation.

Assuming all the characters of `A` (and `B`) are different, then here is a solution with linear complexity. You need a hashmap or something similar, as well as an array of indices, `Y`, of equal length to `A` and `B`.

1 - Put each character of `A` in the hashmap as key, with its index as value.
2 - Look up each character of `B` in the hashmap to get the value `i`, and put its index into `Y` at the position `i`.
3 - Go through `Y` counting the number of times that `Y[i] < Y[i-1]`. That's your number of operations.

Comment: Linear complexity is expected.